# Como fazer um campo data contendo apenas Mês e Ano Html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5, data

Necessito de um campo data contendo apenas Mês e Ano Html de preferencia que habilite na tela algo parecido com um calendário contendo apenas os meses e anos.

obs: Estou usando angularJs, javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com **HTML5** pode usar o `type="month"`

```html
<input type="month">
```

Suportado pelos navegadores:

- Chrome 20+
- Edge 12
- Opera 10.62+

Answer (score -4):

Cria um select COm o mês eos anos.

```
 <div class="mes">
   <select>
      <option>01</option>
      <option>02</option>
      <option>03</option>
      <option>04</option>
      <option>05</option>
      <option>06</option>
      <option>07</option>
      <option>08</option>
      <option>09</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>11</option>
      <option>12</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div class="ano">
   <select>
      <option>1990</option>
      <option>1991</option>
      <option>1992</option>
      <option>1993</option>
      <option>1994</option>
      <option>1995>/option>
      <option>1996</option>
      <option>1997</option>
      <option>1998</option>
      <option>1999</option>
      <option>2000</option>
      <option>2001</option>
   </select>
</div>
```